# Lost trying to use argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm creating a script to automate plethora of related tasks, however I'd like to be able to run specific parts of the script from command line, such as `C:\> python main.py --debug` (or just -d)
Or something like `C:\> python main.py --log` (or just -l)

I've tried a lot of websites and videos but I haven't been able to find a solution. I've read the python docs but I don't really understand it very much yet as I'm very very beginner level. I don't want to have to run `python main.py -l True` or `-l Yes` or anything, I just want to be able to set a boolean to True if `-l` is present.

I'm using arparse and I just want to be able to say, if the script is run with argument "-d", then set variable x to True
Similarly, if script is run with argument "-l" then it would set y to True

I have been able to set up descriptions

```
import argparse

myparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script for logging and analyzing player data')
myparser.add_argument('--debug', '-d', required=False, action='debug_mode', help='Run in DEBUG Mode')
myparser.add_argument('--log', '-l', required=False, action='logger', help='Only run loggers')
myparser.add_argument('--autorun', '-a' required=False, action='enable_autorun', help='Logs data every day')
```

I don't want to require the arguments either, I want them to be optional.

I'm very new to python and I genuinely don't understand this argparse module, any help would be greatly appreciated :))

Comment: I suggest reading the official docs. They are a pretty good tutorial. Most of the others I've seen online are frankly crap.

Comment: Those `action` strings are not valid.  If you want True/False` values use 'store_true'.  Read the docs. `argparse` tagged SO answers might slso help you get started.  Some are advanced, but many help novices get going.

Comment: In the duplicate, use the newer answer by @blhsing.  The longer accepted answer deals with `-foo True` types of inputs, which you don't need.